# Linq query with wildchar in field value

Tags: c#, asp.net, linq, entity-framework

I'd like to have a database field with wildchars. It's kind of reverse wildchar linq search.

So my field would contain "100-50-*", and I would like to find this, when i search for anything starting with "100-50-". So searches like "100-50-10", "100-50-3", "100-50-B" would all find my row.

Edit:
I'm not sure i explained this properly.
I don't know the contents of the database before the search. Field values could be "100-*" or "100-50-*" or "100-50-10". I would like all three records to show up, if i search for 100-50-10.

Thanigainathan's answer was actually pretty close to what i was looking for.

Comment: What's special characters do you use? Only `*` or all from C# regular expression?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please try this one.

```
   var dataSource = new List<string>() { "100-50-*" };
   var filteredData = dataSource.Where(l => "100-50-10".StartsWith(l.Replace("*",string.Empty))).ToList();
```

Comment: This seems to work. Will test it out properly later. Thanks

Comment: I spoke too soon. This also hits these: "1", "100-5", "100-50-1", so the wildchar has no meaning.

Answer (score 1):

You can use something in the lines of

```
string searchString = "100-50-B";
string regex = "[0-9]{3}-[0-9]{2}";

var match = new Regex(regex).Match(searchString).Value;

var matches = DataContext.Table.Where(e => e.StartsWith(match));
```

The regex will extract XXX-XX (only this pattern as ints) and search for items starting with that.

Comment: It seems that this requires me to know, if theres a wildchar in the database and where, before searching

Answer (score 0):

Here's a quick test I did that seems to solve the problem.

```
List<string> test = new List<string> { "100-50-1,", "100-50-2", "100-50-3", "100-60-6" };
var items = (from s in test where s.StartsWith("100-50") select s).ToList();
```

Using StartsWith you can build whatever pattern you're looking for.